# Find Nearest Address Which Has XRef in IDA

Tags: ida

I'm working on an executable. I've searched by string, and found my string appears once in something that looks like table of localized strings + keys. Now I want to find the function which accesses the table and retrieves a localized string. The problem is that the table is big. VERY big. I tried scrolling up until I find XRef, but either I scroll too fast or too slow and I'll never finish. Instead, I'd like for IDA to find the nearest XRef **before** an address. Is there any way to do that?

**P.S.** If you're think I'm doing this wrong, please let me know (I'm still a beginner in reverse engineering) - but answer my question too, nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done with a script but for occasional use a text search will do the trick:

1. <kbd>Alt-T</kbd>
2. String: XREF
3. [x] Search Up

Because text search looks in whole disassembly, including comments, it should find the line with the text 'xref' in the comment.